# Is there an easy way to use asserts in Python to check for results printed on screen

Tags: python, printing, assert

Whereas `assert` in Python is ideal to verify wether certain function calls return an expected output for a given input, could it also be used to check for results printed on screen (i.e., in procedures that return no results but only have side efffects like printing stuff on screen)? The context of this question is how to write such automated tests that I would like to include in an automated grader tool.

Since expect the answer to this question to be: `assert` does not serve this purpose; what other trick could I use then to check the screen output produced by a procedure?

Comment: It might help to be more precise about what `assert` does: it evaluates an *expression*, and raises an exception if that expression is falsy. The trick, then, is to turn your side effect into a value. `print(...)` writes to standard output by default; you can change that with `print(..., file=...)`, and the value of the `file` argument doesn't have to be an open file handle, but can be any file-like object (like an instance of `StringIO`). Now you've replaced the ill-defined "results printed on screen" with the well-defined "value of returned by `StringIO.getvalue`".

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect the standard output to a file and then compare it's content for validity.